# How can I put a psql meta-command in a psql variable to execute it later?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I  create macros of sorts for `psql` by putting the SQL I want to run in a `psql` variable. I "call" the "macro" by just writing `:variablename`.

e.g.

```
psql=> \set example 'SELECT 1, ''string_literal'';'
psql=> :example
 ?column? |    ?column?    
----------+----------------
        1 | string_literal
(1 row)
```

All good so far.

But now I want to toggle some psql settings as part of my macro. In this case, I want to set unaligned tuples-only mode only for this query, then restore it at the end.

How?

```
\set example '\a SELECT 1, ''string_literal''; \a'
```

won't work:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "a"
LINE 1: a SELECT 1, 'string_literal';
        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found so far uses the following behaviours within `psql` meta command parsing:

- Anything within `'single quotes'` is subject to C-string-like backslash-escape processing for `\n` etc. This is important because it means `\a` expands to `a`, `\\a` expands to `\a`, etc.
- Within a single quoted string, single-quotes may be escaped by doubling them, like in SQL literals, so `''` expands to `'`.
- Outside of a quoted string the special sequence `\\` marks the end of meta-command arguments and resumes normal SQL reading.

Thus, it's valid to write:

```
psql=> \a\\ SELECT 1, 'string literal'; \a\\
Output format is unaligned.
?column?|?column?
1|string literal
(1 row)
Output format is aligned.
```

To put that in a `psql` variable, single quote it, doubling the backslashes and doubling any embedded single quotes:

```
psql=> \set example '\\a\\\\ SELECT 1, ''string literal''; \\a\\\\'
psql=> :example
Output format is unaligned.
?column?|?column?
1|string literal
(1 row)
Output format is aligned.
```